# Querying MongoDB doesn't return results

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am attempting to write a PowerShell script that will query mongo and give a true or false value for a document field. I then need to be able to give that value back to polymon. Below is what I have so far (using sample data I have locally), but when I run it, I get no results. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if im entirely wrong on what I have written.

```psh
Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$($mongoDbDriverPath)MongoDB.Driver.dll"

$databaseName = 'bank'
$collectionName = 'users'

$client = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient -ArgumentList "mongodb://localhost:27017"
$server = $client.GetServer()
$database = $server.GetDatabase($databaseName)
$collection = $database.GetCollection($collectionName)

$query = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("age","30")
$results = $collection.FindOne($query)
foreach ($item in $collection.Find($query)) {
    $results += $item
}
Write-Host $results
```

Comment: Do you get any output if you run without `$query`?

Comment: no i get nothing. I did a test to create a test file to dump the output into but that didnt work either. it created the file, but no contents.

Comment: Did you check if the query works in the Mongo shell? MongoDB doesn't error if you query a nonexisting database or collection, but returns an empty result instead.

Comment: When using the proper syntax in mongo, and im using robomongo, the query is successful